# Azure Function app startup error: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have written an Azure Timer Function app and everything was working fine: compiling and running but while I was working on supporting ApplicationInsights, I get the following error now when my application starts up.

```
A host error has occurred during startup operation '3cec5467-dfe8-4965-84a5-65f44b217bce'.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The key ring does not contain a valid default protection key. The data protection system cannot create a new key because auto-generation of keys is disabled.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, Boolean forceRefresh)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRing()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
```

I am not sure where to start.  I re-created a Timer Function app and added my code back to it but still get the same error.  Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Usually error like this occur when you are constructing classes and event get enabled before the constructors complete.  Do you want auto generation of keys?  I suspect you do not.  So you have to make sure any event do not occur until you generate the initial key,  I would put a break point where the error is occuring.  The when you reach the exception look at the menu Debug : Windows : Call Stack and figure out why you are reaching the code that is giving the exception.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what keys its referring to.  I have a local.settings.json file which contains a connection string and storage and dashboard string if that's what you are referring to?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: How do you mean working on supporting ApplicationInsights? Like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-functions-supported-features#sampling? And could you share your code for testing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error.  This is very weird and doesn't make any sense.

Here is my local.settings.json file.  If I have the spelling "CONTAINER_NAME" or "CONTAINERNAME" as the key, it causes the error.  If I just rename it to something else, I have no error.  This doesn't make any sense.  I uncovered this by reconstructing my function app.  "CONTAINER_NAME" and "LOG_FILENAME" were the last items I added to the settings file because I was writing to Azure Blob storage.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "SQLCONNSTR_DefaultConnection": "",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": 1,
    "CALICO_SFTP_URL": "",
    "PORT": 22,
    "USER_NAME": "",
    "PASSWORD": "",
    "SOURCE_DIRECTORY": "",
    "ERROR_DIRECTORY": "",
    "ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY": "",
    "SOURCE_FILE": "",
    "KEY_VAULT_URL": "",
    "PRIVATE_KEY": "",
    "PARAPHRASE": "",
    "CONTAINER_NAME": "",
    "LOG_FILENAME": ""
  }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who offered to help and your suggestions.  Hopefully, someone can make sense of this behavior.